# How to edit the clipboard value using automation anywhere

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

1. I extract a value "10.1.1.0/27" from Excel sheet using `get cell` command, and storing in a system variable `clipboard`
2. Then I have to paste the value in another window page in the format like "10.1.1.0" by removing "/" and "digits after /"

I have done up to step 1 and guide me how to do the second step.

Comment: Please improve your question. I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solution for UiPath.*

The easiest way would be to use the `Split` function of VB.Net.

Therefore, add a `Assign` activity. Create a new variable here called `NewValue`. Give it the following value:

```
"10.1.1.0/27".Split("/")(0)
```

Or you set `10.1.1.0/27` to a variable called InputValue

```
InputValue.Split("/")(0)
```

That command gives back `10.1.1.0` right into your variable `NewValue`

Comment: but this is sample ip the number of digit will differ from case to case

Comment: Sure then use the second: InputValue.Split("/")(0)

Comment: Do not forget to accept and upvote my answer when it solved your issue. Thank you too.

Comment: I am getting cell from excel looks like "22,3333,444,5" I need to paste like first "22" in one column in window page next to paste second "3333" in other column and "444" in other column and "5" in other column. need to automate using automation anywhere how to do this. help me

Comment: This is different to your question. Please open a new one. But in short: you can do that with InputValue.Split(",")(0) for 22 and InputValue.Split(",")(1) for 3333 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest option would be using the `String Operations - Replace` function.

Use these parameters:

- Input: Clipboard
- Find: \/.*
- Replace: *(keep empty)*
- Regular expressions: Yes

Just like [this](https://regex101.com/r/4PmkFR/1).

Comment: I am getting cell from excel looks like "22,3333,444,5" I need to paste like first "22" in one column in window page next to paste second "3333" in other column and "444" in other column and "5" in other column. need to automate using automation anywhere how to do this. help me

Comment: But a regex is more time-consuming and not really needed here. But for sure also a solution.

Comment: @kwoxer What do you mean time consuming? It's a single line of command native to Automation Anywhere and the performance impact is next to nothing on a text this small. You cannot directly call .NET functions in AA, some are available using VBScript, but you don't want to go there unless you have to. If the question was about UiPath, performance was really critical and the developer would feel comfortable coding, then by all means go VB.NET.

Comment: Ohh sorry. I didn't see he has also AA tagged. Yes my solution is only for UiPath. So I take my statement back =)

Comment: @kwoxer No worries, tagging both AA and UiPath confused me too :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the String Operation command on the AA WOrkbench. Will look something like this:
[image]

Comment: I am getting cell from excel looks like "22,3333,444,5" I need to paste like first "22" in one column in window page next to paste second "3333" in other column and "444" in other column and "5" in other column. need to automate using automation anywhere how to do this. help me

Comment: Use the String operation to split that into a list. Then use variable $counter$ to control it.

Comment: I need to extract the data from the specific row and column in the grid table which is in the windows application. By using automation anywhere how to extract the data from specific row and column of the table.